# Почему в C++ при вводе данных в файл на русском языке они записываются в виде непонятных символов?

Tags: c++, кодировка, filestream

У меня есть программа, которая запрашивает имя и фамилию друга и вводит эти данные в текстовый файл. Вот, собственно, эта программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    string name;
    string surname;
    string filePath = "friends.txt";
    string data;

    cout << "Введите имя друга" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Введите фамилию друга" << endl;
    cin >> surname;

    data = name + " " + surname;

    ofstream friendList;
    friendList.open(filePath, ofstream::app);
    friendList << data << endl;
    friendList.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Далее я ввожу вот такие данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого открываю файл `friends.txt`, в который и записывались мои данные. Открываю файл и вижу такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему это происходит, как это исправить и записывать данные в файл на русском языке кириллицей?

Comment: Используйте utf кодировку

Comment: Кодировки разные, переходите в linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что кодировки не совпадают. Судя по символам CP1251 был преобразован в CP866, что логично, т.к. у CMD по умолчанию кодировка CP866, а у текстовых файлов CP1251. Вариантов несколько:

1. Открыть файл в кодировке CP866 (после чего можно преобразовать в
   нужную - CP1251).
2. Сменить кодировку в терминале (system("chcp 1251");).
3. Менять кодировку внутри твоего кода до вывода в файл.